# Problema ao Tratar uma lista de Objetos na jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, controller, arraylist

Estou tento problemas para tratar uma lista que vem do meu controller em minha jsp 
acredito não estar usando a forma correta para tratar e percorrer essa lista

segue meu controller que cria a lista.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewPesquisar(@PathVariable("id") Long id, ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    LOGGER.debug(" O id a ser consultado é {}", id);

    List<Ito> optional = itoService.findByIdFetchAll(id);

    if (optional.isEmpty()) {

        LOGGER.debug(" Não foi possivel localizar o Tipo com o Id:{}", id);

        throw new BusinessException("Não foi possivel Localizar o Tipo de Projeto");
    }



    List<Ito> listaCompletaNomeItos = itoService.findByIdFetchAll(id);



    model.addAttribute("listaCompletaNomeItos", listaCompletaNomeItos);
```

e a jsp onde devo tratar a lista.

```
   <script>



        console.log("${listaNomeItos}");
        listaNomeItosSpringArray = "${listaNomeItos}";
        listaNomeItosSpringArray = listaNomeItosSpringArray
                .replace("]", "");
        listaNomeItosSpringArray = listaNomeItosSpringArray
                .replace("[", "");
        listaNomeItos= listaNomeItosSpringArray.split(",");



        $
                .each(
                        listaNomeItos,
                        function(k, v) {
                        console.log(v);
                            $("#containerItos")
                                    .append(

            '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">'+
                 '<div class="card card-stats">'+
                     '<div class="card-header" data-background-color="green">'+
                        ' <i class="fa fa-hdd-o "></i>'+
                     '</div>'+
                      '<div class="card-content">'+
                    '<p class="category">Empz</p>'+
                        '<h4 class="title">'+ v +'</h4>'+

                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="card-footer">'+
                      '<div class="stats">'+
                            '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o "Style="color: LightSeaGreen";></i> <a href="${uploadIto}"> Upload de Itos </a>'+
                      '</div>'+
                 '</div>'+
               '</div>'+
           '</div>');
    console.log($.trim(v));
    console.log($.trim(k));
                        });


    </script>
```

Comment: E o que é que acontece? E o que é que você espera? Especifique seu problema, por gentileza.

Comment: entao quando eu tento subir dessa forma a lista não vai ate o meu view

Comment: eu preciso dessa lista para poder criar um elemento dentro da view que tenha o nome e o id desse mesmo objeto

Comment: consegue debugar esse js ou visualizar o resultado de: listaNomeItos?

Comment: consigo debugar o js porem o resultado da lista e vazio por que parece que a informação não subui entende

Comment: E quando tu depura isso: model.addAttribute("listaCompletaNomeItos", listaCompletaNomeItos) tem resultado a variavel?

Comment: ate ai a informação chega o problema esta dai para cima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal agradeço a ajuda mais consegui resolver utilizando o forEach muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Vejo que no controller sua lista recebe os objetos mas no jsp ela chega vazia. 
Verifica se estás chamando a taglib do jstl no jsp.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Se o jsp estiver sem ela a página não saberá ler a variável que vem do controller.

Comment: então João a tenho essa e outras taglibs na pagina sim amigo mesmo assim o erro continua.